# Multiple validation for same value in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to validate 2 input text, but how can I validate same input for
dynamic intput text ? meaning input text quantity can be up to 100 or more.

```
<input type="text" id="id1" />
<input type="text" id="id2" />

$('input').blur(function() {
if ($('#id1').attr('value') == $('#id2').attr('value')) {
alert('Same Value');
return false;
} else { return true; }
});
```

Comment: BTW, you can get the value using `$('#id1').val()` instead of `$('#id1').attr('value')`

Comment: Thanks, for the part of my question you have any idea on how to do multiple validation for same input ? @AlonEitan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="id1" onblur="validate()">
<input type="text" id="id2" onblur="validate()">
<p style="display: none">Test</p>

<script type="text/javascript">


function validate() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        if ($('#id' + i).val() == $('#id' + (i - 1)).val()) {
           $( "p" ).show( "slow" );  return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $( "p" ).hide( 1000 );
        }
    }
    return true;
}

</script>
```

What I did is this hope someone can you this in future reference

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check all the inputs are the same (I gather that's what you're trying to do) you could just loop through them by using a function like this:

```
function validate() {
    for (var i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
        if ($('#id' + x).val() !== $('#id' + (x - 1)).val()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Of course, you may want to create inputs themselves using a loop too if you'll have that many on the page.

Comment: I see, so every blur, i will call this function right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly - you can call it instead of the `$('#id1').attr('value') == $('#id2').attr('value')` you had in your question.